# PHP instance find total

Tags: php, html, arrays

I need help with this code.

```
$aBlockVideos = (array) Advancedvideo_Service_Video::instance()->query("","v.total_comment DESC",1,5);
```

How do I make it so it shows the total number of comments for this week?

Comment: Elaborate your question a bit more.

Comment: i want to show 5 videos in a row but have it be the sorted by the total comment of the week so far this is what i have 
 /**
  * Controller
  */
 public function process()
 {
        $aBlockVideos = (array) Advancedvideo_Service_Video::instance()->query("","v.total_comment DESC",1,5);

  if (!count($aBlockVideos))
  {
   return false;
  }

        $this->template()->assign(array(
                'aBlockVideos' => $aBlockVideos[1],
            )
        );

 }

Answer (score 0):

For the code that shows, the variable `$aBlockVideos` returns in an array () the results of the query, therefore, to know the total value of results, just use:

`$TotalRows = count ($ aBlockVideos);`

However, it is not recommended as it may slow down the execution of the script. I suggest you analyze your class and see if there is an appropriate option, for example:

`$Result = mysqli_query ($ con, $ sql);
$NumRows = mysqli_num_rows ($ result);`

Or, leave the processing to the database itself, in large data, you will get very fast execution time, example of your query:

`SELECT COUNT (*) AS qtd FROM table WHERE ...`

The return is the `qtd` field.

This way your execution time will be more agile.

Tip, review your class and see how to implement this suggestion.

Comment: heres what i have so far 
 /**
  * Controller
  */
 public function process()
 {
        $aBlockVideos = (array) Advancedvideo_Service_Video::instance()->query("","v.total_comment DESC",1,5);

  if (!count($aBlockVideos))
  {
   return false;
  }

        $this->template()->assign(array(
                'aBlockVideos' => $aBlockVideos[1],
            )
        );

 }

Comment: You can use the first example: $TotalRows = count ($ aBlockVideos);